# How to setup and use the yOffset property of $anchorScroll in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, anchor-scroll

I use the `$anchorScroll`-service in AngularJS. It works fine. But I have a fixed navigation bar at the top and the scrolling location goes always x-pixels to far.

Now in the [`$anchorScroll` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) there is a property called `yOffset`. According to the documentation it should fix my problem.

I don't know how to use this yOffset-property however, because this specific part has no example.

How can I use the `yOffset`-property of the `$anchorScroll`-service?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is an example that illustrates how to use `yOffset` at the bottom of the [`$anchorScroll` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll).

```
// offset position by 100px down from the top
$anchorScroll.yOffset = 100;
```

This is the example [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k5DCMwxGQ0lmcDSvVGcl?p=preview)

Comment: Never scrolled down enough... How adequate for this question :)

Comment: This can be used right above the $anchorScroll too for individual sets.

Comment: Anybody ever followed the docs and had this not work? I'm in the boat, trying to determine what the "obvious" component is that I am missing. Doesn't seem like there's much to mess up, I just set `$anchorScroll.yOffset = 100;` on a module run then have a `goTo()` function in a controller. Changing the `$anchorScroll.yOffset` value fails to have any effect.

Comment: Wait, you mean that you set it using a global mutable property which can screw up every other call to $anchorscroll ? In what world is this a good idea ?

Comment: I'm using material-design-lite - Material Design Components in CSS, JS and HTML and am attempting to offset an anchorScroll for elements in mdl-layout__content. The offset doesn't work; looks like it's incompatible.

Comment: Setting the yOffset does not work . I did   $anchorScroll.yOffset = -105; in the app run , but it does not seam to work for some reason .

Comment: If you're having trouble getting yOffset working and your URL hashes and anchor IDs are the same, check first that it's not the native browser anchor scroll that you're experiencing - that will not take into account any `yOffset`.